# AngularJS: How to remove event handlers from an element that were added by a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, event-handling

I have an attribute directive that adds event listeners for certain events on an element in the link() function via `element.addEventListener(<event>, handler);`

Eventually, I wish to dynamically remove those handlers based on logic in my controller. How can I do this? I considered just calling removeEventListener on the element in my controller, but I don't have a reference to the handler function since it's in my directive.

Comment: The directive need to provide an option to do that, like using a flag to determine whether to have the listener, or by exposing an api to add/remove the listener

Comment: you can use $emit or $broadcast, also remember remove all listeners in scope.$on('$destroy', ...) to avoid memory leaks

Comment: @EvgenyPopov is that only if I'm removing elements from the page? these elements will stay on the page until the page is closed / the view is changed

Comment: @ArunPJohny okay, exposing an api sounds awesome, how can I expose an api on the directive for use on the controller?

Comment: @PDN yes, on $destroy is only for removing elements, but if you just change a view without page reloading you have to use this

Comment: @PDN just call $scope.$broadcast('someEventName') in controller and add subscription in directive scope.$on('someEventName', function() { /* remove listeners stuff */ })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use to remove event handlers in the end.

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      //Code to remove Event     
});
```

And if you want to remove it in between then you can listen for an event inside directive and **broadcast or emit**  from controller when you want.